# El Android App Bundle no está firmado

Tags: app, apk, google-play-console

Estoy tratando de publicar mi app en Play Store, y tengo problemas al subir el app bundle, ya que me informa que no está firmado. Ya intenté todo, generé mi keystore.jks, generé mi app bundle en modo Release firmado con la keystore, y cuando voy lo subo en una nueva versión en play console, me dice que no está firmado. Mi preferencia para administrar la clave de firma en play console es la siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Debo comentar que la primera prueba interna de mi app, cuando subí el app bundle no mostró este error, ahora estoy intentandolo en una prueba abierta y sufro por ese error. Espero sus respuestas! Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema, en mi caso tenia debuggable en true, lo cambié a false y el error desapareció.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }
        debuggable false
    }
```

}